# What is the use of running two web applications on one application pool?

Tags: sharepoint, web-applications, application-pool

What is the use or benefit of running two web applications on one application pool?

How does that differ from running each web application on its distinct application pool?

Comment: I tried to reword your question to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes, and further improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage is the ability to resource constrain the combination of web applications.  For example: If you wanted to ensure that the two applications combined did not go over a certain amount of Private Memory then you could set that limit on the joint application pool.  If you wanted the combination to not go over 1000MB, that would be more flexibility than having two separate app pools each with a limit of 500MB.  (This is particularly useful if they have different peaks/valleys)